# Rasa agent stop responding after one story has spoken

Tags: python, flask, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I wrote a simple bot using rasa. To handle messages I create the flask app and load the agent into that app. I receive user message and id from the request and put it to agent handle_text method then I got the response. The problem is that after I spoke one story that defined in my story.md my agent stops answering.

Here is my flask app

```
app = Flask(__name__)


# Define rasa interpreter
interpreter = None

# Define rasa agent
agent = None


@app.route('/')
def index():

    # Receive message from request
    message = request.args.get('msg')

    # Receive user id from request
    user_id = request.args.get('uid')

    #  Validation
    if not message:
        return 'No message specified in field \'msg\''
    if not user_id:
        return 'No user id specified in field \'uid\''

    # Put received message into rasa agent
    answers = agent.handle_text(message, sender_id=user_id)

    # Define text for the response
    text = None

    if len(answers) > 0:
        text = "User: {} | {}".format(user_id, answers[0].get('text'))
    else:
        text = "User: {} | Nothing to answer".format(user_id)

    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Load rasa interpreter
    interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter(NLU_PATH)

    # Load rasa agent
    agent = Agent.load(CORE_PATH, interpreter=interpreter)

    app.run()
```

My stories.md is

```
## Simple flow
* greet
  - utter_greet
* bye 
  - utter_bye 
## Order pizza
* greet
  - utter_greet
* order_pizza_type
  - utter_finish_order_pizza
* bye
  - utter_bye
## Story
* order_pizza_type
  - utter_finish_order_pizza
## Generated Story -1054914010798310995
* greet
    - utter_greet
* order_pizza_type{"Country": "mexican"}
    - utter_finish_order_pizza
* bye
    - utter_bye
## New Story
* greet
  - utter_greet
* order_pizza_wish
  - utter_finish_order_pizza
* bye
    - utter_bye
```

and my config.yml

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "nlp_spacy"
- name: "tokenizer_spacy"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
  intent_tokenization_flag: true
  intent_split_symbol: "+"

policies:
  - name: "KerasPolicy"
    featurizer:
    - name: MaxHistoryTrackerFeaturizer
      max_history: 5
      state_featurizer:
        - name: BinarySingleStateFeaturizer
  - name: "MemoizationPolicy"
    max_history: 5
  - name: "FallbackPolicy"
    nlu_threshold: 0.4
    core_threshold: 0.3
```

My expected result

```
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=hello&uid=1"
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=I want to order pizza&uid=1"
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=Bye&uid=1"
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=hello&uid=1"
```

Response

```
> User: 1 | Hey! How are you?
> User: 1 | Ok I will deliver pizza for you
> User: 1 | Bye
> User: 1 | Hey! How are you?
```

But my actual results are

```
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=hello&uid=1"
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=I want to order pizza&uid=1"
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=Bye&uid=1"
$ curl -X GET "https://localhost?msg=hello&uid=1"
```

Response

```
> User: 1 | Hey! How are you?
> User: 1 | Ok I will deliver pizza for you
> User: 1 | Bye
> User: 1 | Nothing to answer
```

As you can see no response for the second message "hello" after one storyline has been spoken.

Comment: Can you share whole project with all these files?

Comment: Ok, I will put it on Github. One moment.

Comment: Here is my repo https://github.com/alexanderbakhmach/rasa_simple_bot.git

Comment: You can debug your bot in the interactive learning mode. The interactive learning modes tells you everything the bot recognizes and how it would react. On top of that you can directly correct errors.

Comment: Maybe it will help if you restart the interaction after the order is finished

Comment: @AleksandrBakhmach Did you solved it? If yes then please share your final answer. And yes, If it's only because of story data, then story file also. Thanks.

Comment: @MauriceDöpke : calling `action_restart` solve my issue. it's a one of default action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as suggested in the comments I'd suggest to use [interactive learning](https://rasa.com/docs/core/interactive_learning/) to debug your bot and create new training stories. Currently you have very sparse training data.

Did you use [augmentation](https://rasa.com/docs/core/policies/#data-augmentation) for the training? If you did not specify the parameter differently, the default augmentation is set to `20`.

If you are using augmentation I'd suggest to also add another short story to handle a standalone `greet`:

```
## Simple flow
* greet
  - utter_greet
```

One more thing:
It is recommended to use general intents and distinguish them by the recognized entities.
Hence, instead of `order_pizza_type` and `order_pizza_wish` it would be better to have an intent `order_pizza` or even `order` and then slots for `food_type`, `product_to_order` (e.g. `pizza`) and so on. If you have very similar intents such as `order_pizza_type` and `order_pizza_wish` NLU will have a tough live to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added more training data and it has fixed my issue.